# Flutter : How to Pop with two nested Navigators?

Tags: flutter

I have a MaterialApp(navigatorKey: *rootNavigatorKey* ) , which has two routes

- '/datoPhotoViewer' without a drawer
- '/' which has a Drawer, this drawer has listItems that pushes the widgets on his child : Navigator(navigatorKey: *navigatorKey* ),

The problem is when i press the back button, whole app closes, My idea was then, catch Back-Button-pressed , and calling the **navigatorKey.currentState.pop()** from the adequate navigatorKey

So to do it, i need WillPopScope .. when I set a WillPopScope on each route, i find that when i press Back button, the app was still closing

So i've decided to delete all the WillPopScope i had, and put only one WillPopScope(onWillPop: onPop) on main.dart where by trying, i find that it catches every 'back button pressed', and changing that **static function onPop** when i open a route with :

```
 setOnPopFunction(Function func){
  onPop = func;
}
```

But when i call this function, onPop function isn't changed ,

Another thing i saw happening : I'm getting logged those weird results when accessing the navigatorKeys

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey();
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

Function onPop ;


    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

onPop = (){


        log("___Navigator1 context "+ ModalRoute.of(rootNavigatorKey.currentContext).toString());

//this prints '___Navigator1 context null' , even though i can push /datoPhotoViewer to Navigator 1

    log("___Navigator2 routeName "+ ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name.toString());

  //always printing '___Navigator2 routeName  /' ,even when this navigatorKey has been pushed to another route


    return Future.value(false);
  };


        return MaterialApp(
            navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey, //Navigator 1 key
            routes: {
              '/': (context) { //Navigator 1 route
                return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: onPop         //this is the only onWillPop function i can get called when pressing back button , Which i'll change with setOnPopFunction()
                  child: MyMainStructure(  //MyMainStructure is a Scaffold with the drawer
                        child: Navigator(
                          key: navigatorKey, //Navigator 2 key

                          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {

                            switch (settings.name) {
                              case '/':                      //Navigator 2 route
                                return MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => TodosLosItemsPage());
                              case '/categoria':             //Navigator 2 route
                                return MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) =>
                                      CategoriaConceptosPage(settings.arguments),
                                );
                            }
                          },

                          initialRoute: '/',   //Navigator 2 initial
                        )),
                );

              },

              '/datoPhotoViewer': (context) =>  //Navigator 1 route
    datoPhotoViewer(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments),
            },
            initialRoute: '/',   //Navigator 1 initial
          ),
        );
      }    
    }

 setOnPopFunction(Function func){
  onPop = func;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i ended up using an external package

https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor

I've disabled the back button for all the app with a

```
WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
            child: ....
```

And making a BackButtonManager class to override the Back Button

```
List<Function> _listeners = List<Function>();

class BackButtonManager {

  static void addCustomFunction(Function func){
     _listeners.add(func);
      BackButtonInterceptor.add(func);

}
  static void resetListeners(){
    _listeners.forEach((element) {
      BackButtonInterceptor.remove(element);
    });
    _listeners.clear();

  }
```

This is the structure of what i do when a new route is opened, on initState i call:

```
    BackButtonManager.resetListeners();
    BackButtonManager.addCustomFunction ((bool asd){

  //handle it
  //for example:    navigatorKey.CurrentState.pop();

// then check which widget is going to be onscreen now , 
// and when this BackButton is pressed , add to BackButtonManager it's 
// BackButtonFunction 

        BackButtonManager.resetListeners();
        BackButtonManager.addCustomFunction ((bool asd){

              //handle the incoming OnScreenWidget

          return false;

        });

      return false;

    });
```

I'd recommend to make a list that represents your stacks of routes, there might be another way , but this works